# Checking input type=date in if statement (empty or !empty)

Tags: php, date, input

Okai, so I was running a check on my website and asked a couple of people if they could register on my page and some of the people managed to get through my registration without setting date (it turned automatically to 00-00-0000).
This is the assigning of the variables (using 1 common submit button).

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
        $passwordone = $_POST['passwordone'];
        $passwordtwo = $_POST['passwordtwo'];
        $name = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $age = $_POST['date'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
```

the statement to check the variables

```
if (!empty($username) && !empty($passwordone) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($age) && !empty($country)
```

How can I write this code so they wont be able to go through without assigning a date?

Comment: What you getting `var_dump($age);` ? Cause your current code seems fine, it won't allowed user to pass through if data field is empty.

Comment: Without adding anything I get a 0.

Comment: Use `!empty(strtotime($age))`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = "^[0-9]{4}-(((0[13578]|(10|12))-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$";
$date = $_POST['date'];
if (!empty($username) && !empty($passwordone) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) &&     !empty($age) && !empty($country) && !preg_match($pattern, $date)
```

Just add this to your validation and it should solved it

Comment: Do I make a new variable or do i add it to my $age variable?

Answer (score 0):

an simple alternative solution.

```
$date = $_POST['date']; 
$date='17-06-2013'; // example
list($d,$m,$y)= explode('-',$date);

if (!empty($username) && !empty($passwordone) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) &&     !empty($age) && !empty($country) && checkdate($m,$d,$y)===true
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different method.

```
if(strlen($_POST['date']==10){

echo $_POST['date'];

}else{

echo "Please Select Date";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `isset($_POST['date'])`?

If you want to validate the content of date as well, see
[Check if variable is a valid date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691949/check-if-variable-is-a-valid-date-with-php)

Comment: Would this turn out the same as !empty? if I get a string value of 0 if nothing is changed that means it has been set. So in theory having !empty is safer.